# java android - how to check drawing in canvas is finish or not?

Tags: java, android, canvas

i have one question,

I've made a project to draw an image. and it worked! but I am confused, I must add a button to check whether someone is really drawing all the parts of the image or not.

This is my code.

`MainActivity.java`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    DrawingView dv;
    private Paint mPaint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        dv = new DrawingView(this);
        setContentView(dv);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    }

    public class DrawingView extends View {

        public int width;
        public int height;
        private Bitmap mBitmap;
        private Canvas mCanvas;
        private Path mPath;
        private Paint mBitmapPaint;
        Context context;
        private Paint circlePaint;
        private Path circlePath;

        public DrawingView(Context c) {
            super(c);
            context = c;
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
            circlePaint = new Paint();
            circlePath = new Path();
            circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
            circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
            circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
            super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

            //mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.asd) //-->here load your image
                    .copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
        }

        private float mX, mY;
        private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

        private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
            mPath.reset();
            mPath.moveTo(x, y);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }

        private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
            float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
            float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
            if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;

                circlePath.reset();
                circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
            }
        }

        private void touch_up() {
            mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
            circlePath.reset();
            // commit the path to our offscreen
            mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            // kill this so we don't double draw
            mPath.reset();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    touch_start(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                   break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touch_move(x, y);
                    invalidate();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    touch_up();
                    invalidate();
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

What from the code can be checked drawing?
and I do not know where to make checking function.

can you help me? thank you :)

Comment: why do you check canvas is finish or not?

Comment: because in that canvas I've set them into an image pattern that should be colored with a finger. and when the canvas / image that has been completed is colored, then the user can go to the next activity. so needed a checking, what the picture was finished, colored or not? what my code above is wrong? Can you help me?